Unknown coin Bitcoin and network regtest combination
I know that this repo of kyuupichan is not supporting Bitcoin anymore
So I cloned this repo of spesmilo instead
However when I run the electrumx_server, I get the following error:
electrumx.lib.coins.CoinError: unknown coin Bitcoin and network regtest combination
Environment Variables:
export DB_DIRECTORY="/home/omarosman23/.electrumx/db"
export NET="regtest"
export COIN="Bitcoin"
export DAEMON_URL="http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:18443"
export SSL_CERTFILE="/home/omarosman23/.electrumx/server.crt"
export SSL_KEYFILE="/home/omarosman23/.electrumx/server.key"
export DB_ENGINE="leveldb"
export CACHE_MB=500
export SERVICES=tcp://:50001,ssl://:50002,wss://:50004,rpc:/

Any insights would be much appreciated!
